# CCParticleExplosion working on Simulator but not on iPhone 4S

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, particles, ccparticlesystem

I am having an issue where a CCParticleExplosion works perfectly on the Simulator and fails on my iPhone 4S.  In the simulator, the particles look fine.  When the explosion happens on my iPhone, there is a dark shadow of the explosion and broken, flickering fragments of the texture used.  Here is my code:

```
bombExplosion = [[CCParticleExplosion alloc] initWithTotalParticles:3];
//bombExplosion = [[CCParticleExplosion alloc] init];

//bombExplosion.autoRemoveOnFinish = YES;
bombExplosion.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage: @"newnhamm_MultiColored_Sparkle_edit.png"];
bombExplosion.speed=100;
bombExplosion.duration = 1.3;
bombExplosion.life = 0.3;
bombExplosion.position = ccp(835,85);

ccColor4F startColor, startColorVar, endColor, endColorVar;
startColor.r = 1.0f;
startColor.g = 1.0f;
startColor.b = 1.0f;
startColor.a = 1.0f;

startColorVar.r = 0.0f;
startColorVar.g = 0.0f;
startColorVar.b = 0.0f;
startColorVar.a = 0.0f;

endColor.r = 1.0f;
endColor.g = 1.0f;
endColor.b = 1.0f;
endColor.a = 1.0f;

endColorVar.r = 0.0f;
endColorVar.g = 0.0f;
endColorVar.b = 0.0f;
endColorVar.a = 0.0f;

bombExplosion.startColor = startColor;
bombExplosion.startColorVar = startColorVar;
bombExplosion.endColor = endColor;
bombExplosion.endColorVar = endColorVar;

[self addChild:bombExplosion];
```

Comment: What's the dimensions of your PNG.  I seem to recall there are rules around the sizing of particle images in Cocos2D.  Can't remember what the sizing rules are but I would try different sizes to see the result. Also what version of Cocos2D are you using?

Comment: My version of cocos2d is: cocos2d-iphone v2.1-rc0a.  The dimensions don't seem to matter.  I tried other images with different dimensions and the same issue happened.  Someone told me that it may be the fact that I said initWithTotalParticles as opposed to simply init.  Does this sound as though it might be a problem?

Comment: Don't think using initWithTotalParticles as opposed to init would be an issue but easiest way to know for sure would be to try it out.  I have a few projects which use initWithTotalParticles so this should be fine.  Have you tried a few different devices?  Maybe this is something particular to the 4S you are making use of?

Comment: Hi Rob Segal, I tested it out now on an iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, and iPhone 5.  All devices had the same issue.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of what the issue looks like?  Maybe I'm just not understanding what the core problem is.

Comment: Here you go: [Image of Issue](http://www.mediafire.com/view/xu4z5mmqm0531vy/Screen_Shot_2013-08-26_at_10.56.20_PM.png)

Comment: Here's how it's supposed to look: [Correct explosion in simulator](http://www.mediafire.com/view/qd4yx6i0caedwbv/Screen_Shot_2013-08-26_at_11.01.13_PM.png)

Comment: This is a bit of a long shot but do you get any errors when adding the texture in your console log? [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage: @"newnhamm_MultiColored_Sparkle_edit.png"];

Comment: I get this: -[CCFileUtils fullPathForFilename:resolutionType:] : cocos2d: Warning: File not found: fire.png.

Comment: However, I get that error every single time with another animation that I programmed and that animation works fine in both the simulator and the iPhone

Comment: I'm running out of ideas here.  If you can host the png somewhere I'd be happy to try it out in a project myself.

Comment: Okay, I think I might try going all the way back to CCParticleSystem.  As for the png, it's open clipart.  Here's the link for the [star](http://openclipart.org/detail/27914/multicolored-sparkle-by-newnhamm)

Comment: That particle texture is massive! 566 × 800 is way to big for an individual particle.  There's a good chance the issue might be that you are running out of memory.  Try resizing it down to 64x64 and see if that works.  I think that might be the source of your problem.

Comment: Nope :( Now there are just smaller shadows and random streaks of yellow.

Comment: I'm wondering if this might be a path discovery issue.  The name for the image you have varies quite a bit in terms of case sensitivity.  Try changing "newnhamm_MultiColored_Sparkle_edit.png" to something like "sparkle.png" and see if that corrects the issue.  The simulator is quite forgiving in terms of case sensitivity but when running on device the rules are very strict and would explain the situation you're encountering.  I've tried this image on simulator and on device (iPod4) and it looks fine.